# NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: not working

Tags: ios, timer, nstimer

I've created a test application with timer before implementing it in my project.
It was the first time I'm using timer.
But the issue is when I implemented timer using `[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: target: selector: userInfo: repeats: ];` , it is not working.
Here is my code,
Interface:

```
@interface uialertViewController : UIViewController
{

    NSTimer *timer;
}

-(void)displayAlert;
-(void)hideandview;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation uialertViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [self displayAlert];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


-(void)displayAlert{

    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(hideandview) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"testing" message:@"hi hi hi" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"continue" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];




    [alert release];
    alert = nil;

}

-(void)hideandview{

    NSLog(@"triggered");

    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    [alert release];

    [self displayAlert];
}

@end
```

**Then I Changed** `[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: target: selector: userInfo: repeats: ];` **with** `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: target: selector:userInfo: repeats: ];` **, It is working**. What was the issue with `timerWithTimeInterval:` ? Am I mising anything in my first implementation ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: timerWithTimeInterval creates the timer but doesn't start it and schedule... does. I think thats the only difference

Comment: @rooster117: then i need to call timers fire method, am i correct ?

Comment: Yeah or just call scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval when you want to start it. Either way

Comment: Well written question posed with detailed code!

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:` and `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` create timers that get automatically added to an `NSRunLoop`, meaning that you don't have to add them yourself. Having them added to an `NSRunLoop` is what causes them to fire.

With `timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:` and `timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`, you have to add the timer to a run loop manually, with code like this:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:repeatingTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Other answers on here suggest that you need to call `fire` yourself. You don't - it will be called as soon as the timer has been put on a run loop.

Comment: Even with the scheduled method, if running in a command line util, you still need to add it do the mainRunLoop by hand, at least in my experience, as well as indicated by : [run run run nsrunloop](http://hackazach.net/code/2013/08/09/run-run-run-nsrunloop/)

Comment: scheduledTimer worked perfectly with this suggestion without having to fire the timer. thank you

Comment: I tried to use the scheduledTimer method without firing it, but it did not work. But I totally agree with your answer that you don't have to add it to the run loop. Thank you for clarifying the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Also one may want to make sure to add timer on the main thread.

```
assert(Thread.isMainThread)
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(YourSelector), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

As a previous answer noted schedule on the main thread, but rather than using assert, put it on the main thread:

```
@objc func update() {
    ...
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
```

And if async is not desired, try this:

```
let schedule = {
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

        if Thread.isMainThread {
            schedule()
        }
        else {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                schedule()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that the `timerWithTimeInterval` method returns a `NSTimer` object that has not yet been fired. To fire the timer you have to use `[timer fire];` On the other hand the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` returns an `NSTimer` that has already been fired.

So, in your first implementation you were just missing `[timer fire];`

Comment: See my post - `[timer fire]` does not "start" the timer, it simply directly calls that method. You need to add the timer to a run loop for it to start.

Comment: It works for once  but for continuous process use @Joseph Humfrey code.