# iOS NSTimer not working?

Tags: ios, ios5, methods, nstimer

This is my exact code, and it doesn't seem to be working. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Note that refreshTimer was already declared in the private interface.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
refreshTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerTest)      userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
-(void)timerTest {
NSLog(@"Timer Worked");
}
```

Comment: set repeats:NO
it worked for me..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Give `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` a try:

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(myMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Quoting: [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058571/nstimer-timerwithtimeinterval-not-working)

`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats`: and `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats`: create timers that get automatically added to an `NSRunLoop`, meaning that you don't have to add them yourself. Having them added to an `NSRunLoop` is what causes them to fire.

Answer (score 7):

There is two-option.

If using a `timerWithTimeInterval`

use a following like it.

```
refreshTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerHandler) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:refreshTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

also mode is two-option. `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` vs `NSRunLoopCommonModes`

more Information. refer a this documentation: [RunLoopManagement](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html)

---

If using a `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`

use a following like it.

```
refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerHandler) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

scheduled timers are automatically added to the run loop.

more information. refer a this documentation: [Timer Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-CJBJCBDE)

### **In summary**

> The "`timerWithTimeInterval`" you have to remember
>   to add the timer to the run loop that you want to add on.
>
> The "`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`" default auto creates a timer that runs in
>   the current loop.