# NSTimer is not repeating as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, repeat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058571/nstimer-timerwithtimeinterval-not-working)

In my app I have the following settings to run an action with a NSTimer:

in the m. file:

```
@implementation MYViewController {
      NSTimer *aTimer;
}
```

Than, when the user clicks the relevant button I have:

```
- (IBAction)userClick:(id)sender {
     aTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                                      target:self 
                                    selector:@selector(doSomethingWithTimer:) 
                                    userInfo:nil 
                                     repeats:YES]; 
     //[aTimer fire]; //NSTimer was fired just once.
}
```

and I also have:

```
-(void)doSomethingWithTimer:(NSTimer*)timer {
     NSLog(@"something to be done");
}
```

I would expect to have a line in the consul saying "something to be done" every one second. The timer is not called even once. I already tried firing the NSTimer using [aTimer fire] but it fires it just once and doesn't repeat as I expect.

Can anyone direct me to how to approach this?

Comment: please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058571/nstimer-timerwithtimeinterval-not-working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
- (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:
```

and then you won't have to add it to run loop manually.

Comment: I thought that I did... have I used it wrongly (see example code in my original question)?

Comment: You used timerWithTimeInterval, not scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the timer to a run loop:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:aTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: I'm familiar with this option. When reading about it, I was not clear regarding to what I should do when I wish the NSTimer to stop working. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Calling invalidate on the timer instance should still do the trick

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is scope. Your `aTimer` variable needs to be a field so it doesn't get GC'd once you leave the `userClick` method e.g.

```
NSTimer *timer;

...

- (IBAction)userClick:(id)sender {
    if (timer != nil && [timer isValid]) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                                             target:self 
                                           selector:@selector(doSomethingWithTimer:) 
                                           userInfo:nil 
                                            repeats:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: Where should the ---NSTimer *timer--- be defined?

Comment: It should be declared as a class field.