# Best way run repeated task while app is active

Tags: ios

I want to run a task in the background while app is active and running. The task should be executed repeatedly in every 2 minutes or so. If the application is inactive then the 'background repeated task' should be paused and it should continue if the app is active again. What is the best way to do this ? Please help.

Comment: Use NSTimer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975562/how-to-pause-play-nstimer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try like this.. Write the following line at where do you want to call the timer..

```
 NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                          target:self 
                                        selector:@selector(timerFired:) 
                                        userInfo:nil 
                                         repeats:YES];
 [aTimer fire];


-(void)timerFired:(NSTimer *) theTimer
  {    
     //Do you your work here..
  }
```

You can also stop the timer with `[aTimer invalidate]; aTimer=nil;` this code.

And also you can check this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058571/nstimer-timerwithtimeinterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058571/nstimer-timerwithtimeinterval-not-working)

Comment: You forgot to fire the timer.

Comment: you can use above lines of code in AppDelegate function named as applicationDidEnterForeground or in ApplicationDidBecomeActive

Comment: No need to fire the timer.