# NSTimer doesn't work on swift

Tags: swift, nstimer

I wrote this code to use a Timer inside of a View Controller:

```
var timer:NSTimer!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: "goTakingPhoto", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    timer.fire()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
 func goTakingPhoto(){
   // doSomething
}
```

But the function `goTakingPhoto` is invoked immediately, not after 2 seconds.
Can anyone help me? Many thanks.

Comment: There's an alternate option for you, if you're just looking to create a delay when the view loads, an `NSTimer` is likely overkill. You can use GCD to add a delay without the `NSTimer` overhead:

    `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.goTakingPhoto()
    }`

It looks a lot more complicated than it is, and I use a macro (Thanks to [Dash][1]) so I don't actually have to type it out each time.


  [1]: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dash-3-api-docs-snippets/id449589707?mt=12&uo=4&at=11lMGu

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("goTakingPhoto"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)}
}

func goTakingPhoto() {
   // doSomething
}
```

Comment: Yeah, he should also remove the `timer.fire()`

Answer (score 0):

I found it works with `NSTimer.scheduledWithTimeInterval(...)`. And you don't have to add `timer.fire()` otherwise the func will be invoked imediately

Reference [here](http://:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058571/nstimer-timerwithtimeinterval-not-working)